# Como permitir añadir "/" a los permalinks de los posts de Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, enlace, reescritura-url

Llevo ya tiempo con este problema y no se ni por donde empezar, todos los **plugins** que he probado **no me funcionan**, o me dejan cambiar el permalink del post pero luego cuando hago click en la URL para visitar la plantilla single.php de ese post, no salta esa plantilla o me salta 404.

Por código he probado a añadirle a los post soporte para que puedan tener post padres(**hierarchy**), pero no cambia su sistema de permalinks, así que no me ha solucionado nada...

El objetivo que busco es que yo pueda hacer este tipo de url para los posts, por ejemplo yo tengo un post que hablo de **España en general**, pero luego tengo otro post que habla de la **comida en España**, entonces mi objetivo es conseguir el siguiente sistema de urls:

www.mibonitoblog.com/españa // esto sería para el post de españa en General

www.mibonitoblog.com/españa/comida // esto sería para el post de comida en España

www.mibonitoblog.com/españa/loquesea // etc...

No puedo tirar de categorías, porque es un **blog ya existente**, si no, podría tirar de usar paginas en vez de posts o bien custom post types, pero al ser un blog ya montado... me esta haciendo quedarme calvo muy joven jajaja xD

**Resumen:** Necesito poder **modificar** los **permalinks** de los **post normales** desde el **admin** para que yo pueda añadir '/' a la url de un post de forma permanente

[image: Permalink]

Como se ve en la foto, si yo quiero modificar la url para que sea **/lechuga/comer/** wordpress me reemplaza los '/' por '-' y necesito concretamente ese formato.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Eso se puede hacer mediante las categorías. No sé por qué dices que al ser un blog ya montado no se puede... ¿qué quieres decir con eso? Si para las entradas que ya existen no quieres que les ponga la categoría en la url no le pones esas categorías y a las nuevas si se las pones.

Comment: eso no puedo hacerlo por categorías porque por ejemplo en la foto la url que acaba en /lechuga/ es un post, si lo hiciera por categorías me daría un error y ademas tendría que aplicarlo a todos los posts, y es solo algo a aplicar a algunos.Lo de al ser montado lo digo, por el tema de custom post types y paginas, no por categorías, pero vamos que las categorías no me sirven para esto.

Comment: Las categorías son **precisamente para eso**. Si configuras bien los permalinks, los posts van a incorporar a la URL  la categoría a la que pertenecen. Querer hacerlo de otra forma es ignorar o querer sustituir una función que hace el propio CMS. Además, como que estás pensando la cosa al revés. `comida`  es una categoría y si al post `lechuga`  tú le pones la categoría `comida`  su URL  te quedaría así: `comida/lechuga` ... es más si declaras `huerto` como sub-categoría de `comida` y marcas lechuga como `huerto` la URL te queda así: `comida/huerto/lechuga`

Comment: El problema es que lo que yo quiero hacer se parecería mas a hijos de posts que a categorías, en el ejemplo que has puesto `comida/huerto/lechuga` sería un post, y luego el otro post sería:  `comida/huerto/lechuga/como-comer` porque ademas, no todos los posts lo tendrian, por eso las categorías no me sirven, porque no lo aplico al 100% de los posts.

Comment: No entiendo bien a qué te refieres con *hijos de posts*... ten cuidado con no inventar una estructura desordenada solamente por capricho, lo puedes pagar caro a nivel de SEO.   Si en una página tú quieres crear un post que explique cómo comer entonces quizá tendrías que pensar en una categoría `instrucciones`  o `formacion` o algo así y poner allí el post que explica `como-comer`
, quedando la URL así: `instrucciones/como-comer`. La estructura organizativa de una página es importante y si tú agrupas las cosas no importa cómo violas normas SEO que te pasarán factura.

Comment: Con hijos de posts me refiero a algo parecido a lo que tiene wordpress con las paginas, que tu puedes asignar una pagina padre a una pagina de forma que la url de la pagina esta compuesta por: dominio/padre/pagina, he intentado implementarlo en los posts sin exito, y no el ejemplo que tu dices no es  el que yo digo, a ver si con este lo ves más claro, `dominio/potasio` sería un post que habla del potasio en **general** y otro post que tendría la url:  `dominio/potasio/alimentos` en el que hablas de que alimentos tienen potasio.

Answer (score 0):

no pillo muy bien tu pregunta, son post, son post_type, son paginas de wordpress, son paginas externas, es un loop y dentro del loop?
Tienes por ejemplo la posibilidad de usar :

```
<?php site_url('/url_del_sito/'); ?>
```

en vez de usar the_permalink. Seria de ayuda si copiaras algo del codigo aqui

Comment: No tengo código porque no se muy bien por donde empezar esto, lo que yo digo es desde el backend, necesito poder editar desde post.php la url del post de forma que wordpress me admita el caracter '/' en el slug.

Comment: Mira, no soy una eminencia en esto, pero creo que no se puede, por que ecada / significa un salto de pagina, y la url de cada post es unica. Puedes cambiarle el nombre de la url pero no añadirle un /

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir eso deberías hacer una categoría, en este caso "Lechuga" y publicar un post dentro de dicha categoría, el nombre puede ser cualquiera y luego se modifica el enlace.

Además en los Enlaces permanentes de Wordpress deberás cambiarlo para que salga dominio.com/categoria/articulo, de esta forma te quedaría bloghsn.local/lechuga/comer/

No hay otra forma, ya que las barras '/' indican cambio de página o directorio.